# How I solve this questions?

Tags: sql

[I tried everything but I can't solve it, someone can help me cause I would like to understand it for getting more experience.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0jev.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use GROUP BY command :

```
SELECT 
  id_unit, COUNT(*)
FROM 
  order_amount 
GROUP BY 
  id_unit;
```

**Results :**

```
id_unit COUNT(*)
kg  40
m3  30
pal 30
```

After if you want to display for each order your script will be :

```
SELECT 
  m.id_order,
  (select count(*) from order_amount m2 where m2.id_order = m.id_order and m2.id_unit = 'kg') as num_kg,
  (select count(*) from order_amount m2 where m2.id_order = m.id_order and m2.id_unit = 'pal') as num_pal,
  (select count(*) from order_amount m2 where m2.id_order = m.id_order and m2.id_unit = 'pal') as num_m3,
  COUNT(*) as total
FROM 
  order_amount m
GROUP BY 
  id_order;
```

**Results :**

```
id_order    num_kg  num_pal num_m3  total
1   5   2   2   8
2   0   2   2   4
3   6   5   5   14
4   5   0   0   10
5   5   3   3   15
```

For more detail [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22be11/4)